# Python Programming homework

Tags: python, html, file-io

First off thank you for your time and answers. My task is to have my program open a text file, read its data so every word is a different string, and creating a HTML document displaying each one of these strings into a random color. So pretty much it wants us to take every word from a text file change each word into a random color and create a HTML document out of it. This is the code i have so far:

```
import random  
def main():
    filename = input("Enter Text File:") 
    infile = open(filename, "r")
    filename2 = input("Enter HTML Document:")
    outfile = open(filename2, "w")
    print("<html>", file=outfile)
    print("  <head>", file=outfile)
    print("  </head>", file=outfile)
    print("  <body>", file=outfile)
    filestring = infile.read()
    file = filestring.split()
    filelength = len(file)
    num = int(random.uniform(0,256))
    num1 = int(random.uniform(0,256))
    num2 = int(random.uniform(0,256))
    i = 0


    for i in range(filelength):
        r = num
        g = num1
        b = num2
        rgb = "{0:02X}{1:02X}{2:02X}".format(r, g, b)
        print('    <span style="color:#{0}">{1}</span>'.format(rgb,                    file[i]),file=outfile)
        i = 0 + 1


    print("  </body>", file=outfile)
    print("</html>", file=outfile)

main()
```

This code works but it does not change each individual word into a random color it just changes all the words into the same color. I appreciate the answers.

Answer (score 9):

Since this is homework, I'll limit my answer to a hint:

You're currently generating one random colour, and applying it to every word. What you should be doing is generating a new random colour for every word.

Answer (score 1):

this code should be in the loop (for i in range(filelength):)

```
num = int(random.uniform(0,256))
num1 = int(random.uniform(0,256))
num2 = int(random.uniform(0,256))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code (I haven't executed it) seems to be correct(ignoring the absence of Exception Handling). You need to change `num`, `num1` and `num2` for each word. That would mean, you need to put `num`, `num1` and `num2` inside the loop `for i in range(filelength):`.

Comment: Thank you all for you answers they helped extremely and the program is working now.

Comment: 1. If you found any answer useful to you, you should click the `tick` button to __accept__ that answer. This would help future readers in directly going to the answer. Read the FAQ, for more details

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import random  
def main():
    filename = input("Enter Text File:").strip()
    infile = open(filename, "r")
    filename2 = input("Enter HTML Document:").strip()
    outfile = open(filename2, "w")
    print("<html><head></head><body>",file=outfile)
    for line in infile:
        for word in line.split():
            (r,g,b)=[int(random.uniform(0,256)) for x in range(3)]
            rgb = "{0:02X}{1:02X}{2:02X}".format(r, g, b)
            print('    <span style="color:#{0}">{1} </span>'.format(rgb,word),file=outfile)
        print("<br>",file=outfile)

    print("  </body>", file=outfile)
    print("</html>", file=outfile)

main()
```